# Need help deleting a specific object from a normal Object Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck on a homework question... so far, using Arrays ONLY I'm having trouble deleting an object in an array by setting it to a null object..I had 3 methods, one method to add an object, one method to return a specific object from an array, one method to delete..so far the add and return objects methods work..but not the delete method...some help guys??

this is the class for the arrays and methods...I'm testing the methods in a main method

```
public class Book {

    public void addContact(Contact[] contactBook)
    {
        int slots = 0;
        for(Contact i : contactBook)
            if (i == null)
                slots++;

        if(slots == 0)
            System.out.println("Contact book full..can't add anymore!");

        else
        {
            String name = Keyboard.readString("Enter name: ");
            int id = Keyboard.readInt("Enter "+name+"'s id: ");
            String classroom = Keyboard.readString("Enter "+name+"'s class: ");
            int number = Keyboard.readInt("Enter "+name+"'s mobile: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < contactBook.length; i++)
            {
                if(contactBook[i] == null){
                    contactBook[i] = new Contact(name,id,number,classroom);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }//end else

    }//end method

    public Contact getContact(Contact[] contactList)
    {
        Contact contact = null;
        int id = Keyboard.readInt("Enter student id: ");

        try
        {
            for(Contact i : contactList)
            {
                if(i.id == id)
                {
                    contact =i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Student ID:"+id+" does not exist..");
        }

        return contact;
    }//end getContact

    public void deleteContact(Contact[] contactList)
    {
        Contact delete = getContact(contactList);

        for(Contact i : contactList)
        {
            if(i!=null)
                if(delete.id == i.id)
                {
                    i = null;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }//end delete

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Contact[] contacts = new Contact[200];
        Book newBook = new Book();

        newBook.addContact(contacts);

        for (Contact i : contacts)
            if(i != null)
                System.out.println(i);

        newBook.deleteContact(contacts);

        for (Contact i : contacts)
            if(i != null)
                System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

this is the class of the object
    public class Contact {

```
    String name;
    String classroom;
    int id;
    int number;

    Contact(String name, int id, int number,String classroom)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.number = number;
        this.classroom = classroom;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ""+name+", student id: "+id+" class:"+classroom+" mobile:"+number;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use ArrayList instead. It'll give you more commands to manipulate your object array. You can easily remove an object from ArrayList then.

Comment: well i'm not allowed to use ArrayList..:(

Comment: Thats really bad. Well!! then you can adopt the way of removing the contents from a file.Means, create another array of size-1.copy all contents excluding the obj you wanna delete to new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterator does return a copy of the reference to the Contact object. You are setting this copy to null and not the object that is stored in the array.

Use something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<contactList.size; i++) {
    if(delete.id == contactList[i].id) {
        contactList[i] = null;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use an enhanced for loop that way. You should just use a normal for loop and do `contactList[i] = null` where i is the index. Here's some [guidelines](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html)

Where the for-each is appropriate
Altho the enhanced for loop can make code much clearer, it can't be used in some common situations.

- Only access. Elements can not be
  assigned to, eg, not to increment
  each element in a collection.
- Only    single structure. It's not
  possible    to traverse two
  structures at once,    eg, to compare
  two arrays.
- Only    single element. Use only for
  single    element access, eg, not to
  compare    successive elements.
- Only forward.    It's possible to
  iterate only forward    by single
  steps. At least Java 5.    Don't use
  it if you need    compatibility with
  versions before    Java 5.

Comment: so i can only assign that variable from the enhanced for loop to another variable instead?

Comment: @Shizmumaru18, see my edit, it contains some basic guidelines now